# Left rotation bitwise operation in Elixir/why is the signed left shift missing?

Tags: bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators, elixir

Disclaimer: I'm extremely naive when it comes to bitwise ops, so dumbing down is appreciated.

I'm basically trying to perform a left rotation in Elixir, based on some equivalent Java I'm working from (I need to port a small chunk over).

```
public static long rotateLeft(long l, int shift) {
    return (l << shift) | l >>> (64 - shift);
}
```

Normally I wouldn't be so blunt about what it is that I'm working from, however I believe it's relevant due to the use of the `<<` operator (which doesn't appear to exist in Elixir/Erlang).

Is there some obvious way to replicate the above behaviour in Elixir that I'm missing? I've searched for implementations without the operator, but it appears that most other languages have it and so it hasn't come up anywhere. One thing which did come up was `X << Y == X * 2 * Y`, and so I implemented like this:

```
def rotate_left(l, shift) when is_number(l) and is_number(shift) do
    (l * 2 * shift) ||| l >>> (64 - shift)
end
```

However, running a test through both languages (`rotate_left(2461839666708829781, 13)`) provides different results in each language - so I guess I made a mistake.

If anyone can lend a hand/explain what I'm missing here (I assume there's a reason this operator doesn't exist), it'd be appreciated. I've tried to cover everything in case it's due to specific numbers etc, but if I've missed anything important just let me know.

Also; if it's not possible with Elixir, I'm perfectly happy to drop down to Erlang. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You want to use [the `Bitwise` module](http://elixir-lang.org/docs/v1.1/elixir/Bitwise.html):

```
iex(1)> use Bitwise
nil
iex(2)> 3 <<< 8 ||| 3 >>> (64 - 8)
768
```

Comment: Is `<<<` equivalent to `<<`?

Comment: Yes, except that in Elixir and Erlang, integers are arbitrary precision, so it doesn't matter if values exceed the maximum 64 bits can hold. Because of this, you'll get a different result than you would in Java or C/C++. You can limit the result to 64 bits using bitwise-and: `((val <<< shift) ||| (val >>> (64 - shift))) &&& 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF`.

Comment: Thank you! I've been banging my head against the precision thing for a while. Can you sum up exactly how the AND is limiting the bits?

Comment: The hexadecimal value `0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF` is 64 bits in size and is composed of all 1s. Performing a bitwise-and against it of some value means that all bits of that value that fit in 64 bits are preserved, while any bits of the value that extend above 64 bits are effectively bitwise-anded with 0, so they too become 0 and are thus dropped.

Comment: Awesome, thanks for the tip. However, I've been profiling my code and it seems this is the slowest piece (applying the mask, although it is called often). Is there a way to avoid having to apply the mask in the first place?

Comment: I suppose you could try dropping to Erlang, where the left shift is named `erlang:'bsl'/2`, right shift `erlang:'bsr'/2`, and AND and OR are `erlang:'band'/2` and `erlang:'bor'/2` respectively (and note that in Erlang the single quotes shown are necessary to distinguish the function name atoms from the operators of the same name). Not sure that will give you much of a speedup, though. If you get really desperate you could implement a [simple NIF](http://www.erlang.org/doc/tutorial/nif.html) to perform the operations instead.

Comment: Cool, thank for the tip on where to look in Erlang, I'll try that out. I've been considering a NIF but really would like to avoid. Thanks for all the help!

Comment: Just to let you know; dropping to Erlang was actually marginally slower. However, implemented a NIF and we're good to go; far faster! Thank you again!

Comment: Sounds perfect. This is a great use for a NIF -- it's small, focused, and simple, yet still provides measurable value for your application.